# How to update Magento core column from type int to decimal using declarative schema?

Tags: magento2, declarative-schema, db-schema

I want to update the core table column from type int to decimal.

`<column xsi:type="int" name="column_name" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false" identity="false" default="0" comment="comment"/>`

I have updated the column as
`<column xsi:type="decimal" name="column_name" scale="2" precision="20" nullable="false" unsigned="true" default="0" comment="comment" />`
in my custom modules declarative schema.

While upgrade I am facing this exception.

Element 'column', attribute 'padding': The attribute 'padding' is not allowed.

Element 'column', attribute 'identity': The attribute 'identity' is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

```
app\code\Company\Ui\etc\db_schema.xml

<?xml version=""1.0""?>
<schema xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=""urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd"">
    <table name=""catalog_product_entity_varchar"" resource=""default"">
        <column xsi:type=""decimal"" length=""512"" name=""value"" nullable=""true"" comment=""Value""/>
    </table>
</schema>
```